# Json to nested list : First node not captured

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the following javascript function to convert a JSON to an html list but because the first node is not well captured the script don't work.
To work with le NestedSortable jQuery plugin, all nodes must be encapsulated in a div tag.
Also the first node (named Flare) should content all of his childrens and not be a unique node on top.
Thx for your lights

```js
function getList(item, $list) {

  if ($.isArray(item)) {
    $.each(item, function(key, value) {
      getList(value, $list);
    });
    return;
  }

  if (item) {
    console.log(item);
    var $li = $('<li />');
    if (item.name) {
      $li.append($('<div>' + item.name + '</div>'));
    }
    if (item.children && item.children.length) {
      var $sublist = $("<ol/>");
      getList(item.children, $sublist)
      $li.append($sublist);
    }
    $list.append($li)
  }
}

$(function() {

  var $ol = $('<ol id="sTree2" class="sTree2"></ol>');

  $.getJSON('https://bitbucket.org/john2x/d3test/raw/2ce4dd5112448088fe357b8179d1088ef19524b8/d3/examples/data/flare.json', function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
      getList(value, $ol);
    })
  });

  //getList(value.node, $ul);

  $ol.appendTo("#main-lists-container");

  $('.sTree2').nestedSortable({
    disableNesting: 'no-nest',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    maxLevels: 0,
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div',

    /* The magic tric: */
    connectWith: '.sortable'
  });
});
```

```css
ol.sTree{ padding:0px; background-color:#151515; }
ol.sTree2 li, ol#sortableListsBase li { padding-left:50px; margin:5px; border:1px solid #3f3f3f; background-color:#3f3f3f; }
ol li div { padding:7px; background-color:#222; Nborder:1px solid #3f3f3f; }
ol li, ol li div { border-radius: 3px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>

<div id="main-lists-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main problem was that you re calling `getList` inside the each function... but the object returned from the http call its not an array

```js
function getList(item, $list) {

  if ($.isArray(item)) {
    $.each(item, function(key, value) {
      getList(value, $list);
    });
    return;
  }

  if (item) {
    console.log(item);
    var $li = $('<li />');
    if (item.name) {
      $li.append($('<div>' + item.name + '</div>'));
    }
    if (item.children && item.children.length) {
      var $sublist = $("<ol/>");
      getList(item.children, $sublist)
      $li.append($sublist);
    }
    $list.append($li)
  }
}

$(function() {

  var $ol = $('<ol id="sTree2" class="sTree2"></ol>');

  $.getJSON('https://bitbucket.org/john2x/d3test/raw/2ce4dd5112448088fe357b8179d1088ef19524b8/d3/examples/data/flare.json', function(json) {
      
      getList(json, $ol);
   
  });

  //getList(value.node, $ul);

  $ol.appendTo("#main-lists-container");

  $('.sTree2').nestedSortable({
    disableNesting: 'no-nest',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    maxLevels: 0,
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div',

    /* The magic tric: */
    connectWith: '.sortable'
  });
});
```

```css
ol.sTree{ padding:0px; background-color:#151515; }
ol.sTree2 li, ol#sortableListsBase li { padding-left:50px; margin:5px; border:1px solid #3f3f3f; background-color:#3f3f3f; }
ol li div { padding:7px; background-color:#222; Nborder:1px solid #3f3f3f; }
ol li, ol li div { border-radius: 3px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>

<div id="main-lists-container"></div>
```

Comment: many thanks. Maybe you can show me how to make the 1st node the container of all the rest of the list as it should be ?